# Reverse tunnel with 4 participants (really a mess)

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, ssh-tunnel, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a server (Win 2008) and a desktop PC (Win 7) at my work behind a firewall. The server doesn't has internet connection for security (actually, it is in a remote datacenter), and the desktop PC has a Logmein client installed, so I can use this PC from my house, and connect me to the server.
Now I need to connect me to the MS SQL Server in the server from a MS SQL Server client in my home, but I can't figure out how can make a remote tunnel like that... to be more explicit:

```
 ______________________________________________
|              Firewall at work                |
|  ________________        __________________  |
| |(1)             |      |(2)               | |
| | Win2008 Server |      |   Desktop Win7   | |
| |  (MS SQL Srv)  | <--- | (Logmein & inet) | |
| |________________|      |__________________| |
|______________________________________________|


  _________________  at home  _________________
 |(3)              |         |(4)              |
 |    Linux PC     | <-----> |      Win 7      |
 | SSH Virtual Srv |         | (MS SQL Client) |
 |_________________|         |_________________|
```

I need to access from **(4)**'s *MS SQL Client* to **(1)**'s *MS SQL Server*... I think I should make a reverse ssh tunnel with Putty or something like that from **(2)** to **(3)** to open a port who redirects all incoming traffic in a certain port in **(3)** to **(1)** through **(2)**.
I don't know if really I need (3) to make the ssh tunnel, if it not to be used, should be even better.
The desktop PC with Logmein and direct access to the server has a really poor internet connection, so it's really difficult to work like that.

Sorry for my bad english...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not overly familiar with LogMeIn, but my understanding is it is simply a remote display session that uses a hosted service to traverse NAT easily.  If that's the case, I don't believe what you're looking to accomplish is possible as there's no way to tunnel anything except remote mouse and keyboard access to your home PC.  It sounds like the best answer would be to use (or implement) a real VPN solution.

Comment: Yes, a VPN is the best solution, but unfortunately its implementation does not depend on my